# How to say "I'm sorry for such a bother"

Tags: politeness

I am in the middle of constructing my email to my colleague and I am out of words on how to say "I'm sorry for such a bother".

Is there any other way of saying it politely?

Comment: *... regret the inconvenience*? That's a bit too formal.

Comment: How will you say if you are making a follow-up of your email and then the sender will reply to you "i'm sorry for the late response. i will get back to you by tomorrow. i am quite busy today" ...is it appropriate to say, "it's alright and i will expect your response to my query by tomorrow. i'm sorry for such a bother." or is there any other words you can suggest?

Comment: I learned a phrase from a Amazon customer service representative: "sorry for the hassle". May it help.

Answer (score 10):

"I apologise for the inconvenience".

Answer (score 5):

"*I'm (so) sorry. I didn't mean to be [**such a bother**](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=5GKgi4LbR00C&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=%22sorry+i+didn%27t+mean+to+be+such+a+bother%22&source=bl&ots=btlU5O3gpc&sig=-29vo9Ot2FAAHzA0pfgFOBkVuuE&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=b_1yU4TaMsfK0QXQ9oGgCg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22sorry%20i%20didn%27t%20mean%20to%20be%20such%20a%20bother%22&f=false)*."

Answer (score 1):

"I am sorry for having bothered you".

"I am sorry for having disturbed you".

Answer (score 1):

Some other possibilities:

- I am really sorry for having troubled you so much.
- I feel sorry for disturbing you and interrupting your routine.
- I am really sorry for bothering you a lot, thus eating up much of your time.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bother you but please could you help me with this email.

Answer (score 0):

"Excuse me" (appropriately voiced) is one way to say it. "Please excuse me" another.

Example: You accidentally bumped into someone. Before she has a chance to get too upset, saying "Excuse me" usually indicates that you are aware that you caused offense, and that you are at least somewhat apologetic for the offense.